# Click and press-release on same button

Tags: android, onclick, ontouch

I implemented my own camera to capture image and video. I want to perform two actions on the same button.

1. When the button is clicked I want to execute code for image capture.
2. When I continuously press the button I want to start recording and when I release the button I want to stop recording.

Suppose I have 3 methods for above task namely captureImage(), startVideo() and stopVideo().

How to implement the above two actions on the same button? When should I call above three methods?

I tried using onClick, ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP, however, in this case onClick never gets called. Always ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved it. On ACTION_DOWN start video recording after 1 second. On ACTION_UP check if you are capturing video then stop capturing otherwise capture image and cancel video capture handler.

```
private Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        isImage = false;
        startRecording();
    }
};


mCaptureButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // Start recording after 1 sec
                    isImage = true;
                    mHandler = new Handler();
                    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // If video recording was started after 1 sec delay then stop recording
                    // otherwise capture image
                    if(isImage) {
                        // Cancel handler for video recording
                        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
                        // Capture image
                        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
                    } else {
                        // Stop video recording
                        stopRecording();

                    }
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [onTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html)

this will return MotionEvent with the desired events ACTION_UP ACTION_DOWN ...

Answer (score 0):

use OnTouchListener and OnClickListener :

```
View v = find....;
    v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //capture();
        }
    });
    v.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            int action = motionEvent.getAction();

            if(action==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)startRecording();
            if(action==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)stopRecording();
            return true;//return true to avoid onClick...
        }
    });
}
```